# Custom Java Servlet Filter

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I'm writing my first ever `javax.servlet.Filter` impl and am trying to write the portion of the `doFilter` method where I prevent the request from going any further in the chain:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response)
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    // Check for some stuff in the request...
    boolean passesInspection = inspect(request);

    if(!passesInspection)
        // How do I prevent the request from going any further?
        // I don't want it even getting to the servlet at this point!
}
```

How do I "block" the request from even making it to the listening servlet? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply don't call `chain.doFilter()`. The `doFilter()` call is what progresses the call. Don't call this and the processing stalls. This is not a good design however. You need to at least inform the caller

Comment: You mean this won't send back an HTTP 500 error, or something else? If so, what's the best practice here? Flag something on the request (if so, how?) and then allow it to arrive at the servlet, then have the servlet send back an HTTP 500 (or something appropriate)?

Comment: @TicketMonster, no, it's on you to use the `HttpServletResponse` to communicate back to the user whatever you please. `500` indicates a processing error that the server/container recognises. What you appear to want to do is simply stop processing, a condition the container cannot anticipate or recognise

Comment: +1 for nice answer. @TicketMonster one thing you could do is to redirect to another servlet/JSP via `sendRedirect()`.

Comment: I'm more inclined towards a 4xx error, since failing the "inspection" seems to be an error on the client side. (For instance, you have decided to forbid access to some resource based on the remote IP or the value of the User-Agent header).